# Unable to access AWS Elasticsearch cluster, IAM policy issue

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-elasticsearch

I'm unable to access AWS ES cluster that has the following access policy, My IP is one of the IP listed, please advise if you there is something missing.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:domain/xxxx-xxxxx-poc/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "52.000.000.07",
            "54.00.000.000"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:role/xxxxx-prod-eb-role",
          "arn:aws:iam::OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:role/xxxx-staging-eb-role"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:domain/xxxx-xxxxx-poc/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Need some more information. How is this set up? Is it build in VPC mode or Public mode? That makes a world of difference on how you access the AWS ES Domain. Also, you ARE using AWS ES Service and didn't set this up manually on EC2 instances right?

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging, I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:role/xxxxx-prod-eb-role",
          "arn:aws:iam::OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:role/xxxx-staging-eb-role"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:domain/xxxx-xxxxx-poc/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "52.000.000.07",
            "54.00.000.000"
         ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There is some more detail here in my [repo wiki page](https://github.com/Talderon/AWS_CloudFormation/wiki/AWS-ElasticSearch-Service-Plus-Cognito---How-To-Put-It-All-Together)

Comment: I would also suggest you use CIDR block notation for the IP's... "52.000.000.07/32" rather than the IP alone.